# Detect the impact of changes in an application

Tags: code-metrics

I have an assignment that consists of creating a method to detect the impact of changes in an application. Can anyone help me with some instructions? I don't know where to begin, and need someone to put me on the right track.

Comment: Consider "diff" or "SmartDifferencer".

Answer (score 0):

For .NET platform, you can use the tool [NDepend](http://www.ndepend.com/) for detecting the impact of changes in a .NET application (Disclaimer: I am the lead developer of this tool).

NDepend provides the facility to write C# LINQ queries to query your code base, but also to query diff between 2 different versions of your code bases. Around [200 default LINQ queries](http://www.ndepend.com/DefaultRules/webframe.html) (code rules) are provided and it is easy to write your own.

For example the default code rules below, list methods that became more complex between two versions:

```
// <Name>Avoid making complex methods even more complex (Source CC)</Name>
// To visualize changes in code, right-click a matched method and select:
//  - Compare older and newer versions of source file
//  - Compare older and newer versions disassembled with Reflector

warnif count > 0 
from m in JustMyCode.Methods where
 !m.IsAbstract &&
  m.IsPresentInBothBuilds() &&
  m.CodeWasChanged()

let oldCC = m.OlderVersion().CyclomaticComplexity
where oldCC > 6 && m.CyclomaticComplexity > oldCC 

select new { m,
    oldCC ,
    newCC = m.CyclomaticComplexity ,
    oldLoc = m.OlderVersion().NbLinesOfCode,
    newLoc = m.NbLinesOfCode,
}
```

The result can be shown live in Visual Studio, or in HTML+js reports:

[image: Diff complexity with NDepend]

In the Rules groups **Code Quality Regression** and **Code Diff Summary** many others default code rules will help you list impact of diff/changes in terms of code quality, code structure and code maintainability. [A 14 days full featured trial is available for download](http://www.ndepend.com/NDependDownload.aspx).